# Insert foreign key values using stored procedure in target table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables like this:

```
create table tblempdetail
(
     id int primary key,
     name nvarchar(20),
     email nvarchar(20) unique
)
```

and:

```
create table tblemployee
(
    empid int,
    month nvarchar(20),
    year nvarchar(20),
    salary int
)
```

I have given reference as:

```
alter table tblemployee 
    add constraint tblemployee_empid_FK 
    foreign key (empid) references tblempdetail(id)
```

I want to create a procedure to fill values in `tblemployee`... where `empid` should be filled automatically taking reference from     `tblempdetail`

Comment: What's the source that you will use to populate tblEmployee?  Specifically, what data point(s) will you have in your source to select the proper tblEmpDetail record?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Why **on earth** are you using `nvarchar(20)` for `month` and `year` which are **clearly** numerical values?? You should **always** use the most appropriate type - here it would be anything numeric, e.g. `INT` or `SMALLINT` ..... but most **certainly NOT** `nvarchar(20)` !!

Comment: actually sir i am new to sql server so just wants to learn the concepts of this technology

Answer (score 1):

First make `tblempdetail.id` an identity column

```
create table tblempdetail
 (id int identity primary key,
   name nvarchar(20),
   email nvarchar(20) unique)
```

Then

```
Create procedure SaveEmployee
  @name nvarchar(20) = null,
  @email nvarchar(20) = null,
  @month nvarchar(20) = null,
  @year nvarchar(20) = null,
  @salary int = null
As
 Set NoCount On
 Declare @id int

    Insert tblempdetail(Name, email) 
    Values(@name, @email)
    Set @id = scope_Identity()

    Insert tblemployee (empid, month, year, salary)
    values( @id, @Month, @year, @salary)
 return 0
```

However, let me strongly suggest you read and research comment from @marc_s above. Your schema design is very poor, and small amount of research into proper design (varchars for dates or portions of dates is bad) will save you a great deal of heartache later on.

Comment: what to do if i have already filled values in tblempdetail and just insert the values into tblemployee

Comment: You have entered the ids, names and emails but have not entered any of the month, year, or salary data? If so, then you need to insert the values manually, one record at a time. If it was me, depending on the volume of data involved, I'd delete it all and start over with a better design.